# Could not load file or assembly 'AdaptiveCards.Html'

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

After upgrading to bot version v3.8 and installing adaptive cards from Nuget package manager, i build my bot solution. Everything works fine but when i use ngrok to make my local address public, i'm getting an error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'AdaptiveCards.Html' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The
>   assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not
>   fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131045)

Code :

```
                    AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();
                    card.Speak = "hellooooooo";

                    card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                    {
                        Text = "Adaptive Card design session",
                        Size = TextSize.Large,
                        Weight = TextWeight.Bolder
                    });

                    // Add text to the card.
                    card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                    {
                        Text = "Conf Room 112/3377 (10)"
                    });

                    // Add text to the card.
                    card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
                    {
                        Text = "12:30 PM - 1:30 PM"
                    });

                    // Add list of choices to the card.
                    card.Body.Add(new ChoiceSet()
                    {
                        Id = "snooze",
                        Style = ChoiceInputStyle.Compact,
                        Choices = new List<Choice>()
    {
        new Choice() { Title = "5 minutes", Value = "5", IsSelected = true },
        new Choice() { Title = "15 minutes", Value = "15" },
        new Choice() { Title = "30 minutes", Value = "30" }
    }
                    });

                    // Add buttons to the card.
                    card.Actions.Add(new HttpAction()
                    {
                        Url = "http://foo.com",
                        Title = "Snooze"
                    });

                    card.Actions.Add(new HttpAction()
                    {
                        Url = "http://foo.com",
                        Title = "I'll be late"
                    });

                    card.Actions.Add(new HttpAction()
                    {
                        Url = "http://foo.com",
                        Title = "Dismiss"
                    });

                    // Create the attachment.
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
                    {
                        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                        Content = card
                    };


                    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    await context.PostAsync(message);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using .NET Standard and did you upgrade?

We just published a new version of the package which dropped the .NET Standard requirement from 1.6 to 1.3.  I am wondering if there is a messed up binding redirect.  You might try uninstalling and then re-installing.

Comment: When i used to search for adaptive cards, there is a multiple packages. Which of them should i add to my bot project ?

Comment: Microsoft.AdaptiveCards contains the object model for creating and serializing adaptive cards.

Microsoft.AdaptiveCards.Html is a library for converting an adaptive card into HTML. 

If all you are doing is producing a card you don't need the HTML library

Comment: Is it possible to use HTML library for other cards ? #maybeThisIsStupidQuestion :D